# Cannot generate buttons through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add formatting options to the commenting box on www.8ch.net / www.8chan.co through the user javascript feature.

Here is a script that does work:

```
/* load_js("http://example.com/script.js"); */

load_js("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js")

/*<![CDATA[*/
function formatText(el,tagstart,tagend){
var selectedText=document.selection?document.selection.createRange().text:el.value.substring(el.selectionStart,el.selectionEnd);// IE:Moz
var newText=tagstart+selectedText+tagend;
if(document.selection){//IE
document.selection.createRange().text=newText;
}
else{//Moz
el.value=el.value.substring(0,el.selectionStart)+newText+el.value.substring(el.selectionEnd,el.value.length);
}
}
/*]]>*/

var formattingButtonsRow = "<tr><th>Formatting</th><td> Test </td></tr>";

$("table:first-of-type tbody:last tr:nth-child(3)").after(formattingButtonsRow);
```

and here is the one that doesn't:

```
/* load_js("http://example.com/script.js"); */

load_js("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js")

/*<![CDATA[*/
function formatText(el,tagstart,tagend){
var selectedText=document.selection?document.selection.createRange().text:el.value.substring(el.selectionStart,el.selectionEnd);// IE:Moz
var newText=tagstart+selectedText+tagend;
if(document.selection){//IE
document.selection.createRange().text=newText;
}
else{//Moz
el.value=el.value.substring(0,el.selectionStart)+newText+el.value.substring(el.selectionEnd,el.value.length);
}
}
/*]]>*/

var formattingButtonsRow = "<tr><th>Formatting</th><td> <input type="button" value="Red Text" onclick="formatText(body,'==','==')"></input> </td></tr>";

$("table:first-of-type tbody:last tr:nth-child(3)").after(formattingButtonsRow);
```

I cannot figure out why the second one does not generate a button.

Comment: Look closely at the syntax highlighting here and you'll easily spot your mistake.

Comment: Look at your JavaScript error console (or [jshint](http://jshint.com/)). You have at least one very obvious syntax error that it will scream about.

Comment: You could perhaps help yourself, if you lay a little bit more effort into a clear code alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var formattingButtonsRow = "<tr><th>Formatting</th><td> <input type="button" value="Red Text" onclick="formatText(body,'==','==')"></input> </td></tr>";
```

to that line:

```
var formattingButtonsRow = '<tr><th>Formatting</th><td> <input type="button" value="Red Text" onclick="formatText(body,\'==\',\'==\')"></input> </td></tr>';
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I don't know how I couldn't see this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: (escaped)

```
    /* load_js("http://example.com/script.js"); */

load_js("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js")

/*<![CDATA[*/
function formatText(el,tagstart,tagend){
    var selectedText=document.selection?document.selection.createRange().text:el.value.substring(el.selectionStart,el.selectionEnd);// IE:Moz
    var newText=tagstart+selectedText+tagend;
    if(document.selection){//IE
        document.selection.createRange().text=newText;
    }
    else{//Moz
        el.value=el.value.substring(0,el.selectionStart)+newText+el.value.substring(el.selectionEnd,el.value.length);
    }
}
/*]]>*/

var formattingButtonsRow = "<tr><th>Formatting</th><td> <input type=\"button\" value=\"Red Text\" onclick=\"formatText(body,'==','==')\"></input> </td></tr>";

$("table:first-of-type tbody:last tr:nth-child(3)").after(formattingButtonsRow);
```